# Can Apper and Muon be used to install and update in 23.04?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, 23.04, discover-software-center, muon-package-manager

I can still use [Apper](https://apps.kde.org/apper/) in Kubuntu 23.04 to install stuff, not only because I like its interface, which is both clear and detailed (while that of Discover is neither), but also when I want to install the standard deb and not a snap program. At least that's what I think.

Is it otherwise?

I see that Discover works well now and has options to select between snap, deb or flatpak, and I do use it to update the system, but these alternative are still available.

For example, [Muon](https://apps.kde.org/muon/) (as alternative to Synaptic) is the only clear solution I know to lock a program to a certain version. Like Apper, it *can* be used to install, uninstall and update. But I expect some overall limitation, including snaps, for example.

What are the limitations of these programs these days in Ubuntu/Kubuntu?

I have noticed that Apper must be run with a modified command in order to get in Kubuntu the administration rights a software manager needs:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true apper --updates
```

Comment: Please let me know what's wrong before or after down-voting!